# JOptionPane showInputDialog null?

Tags: java, input, null

I have a JOptionPane.showInputDialog.
How I can control if the user press the button cancel?

```
String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

```
if (name==null) {
//What you want to happen...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If user pressed Cancel, then `name` is `null`. If he didn't write anything but pressed OK then `name` is the empty string `""`.